# Javascript wait asynch retriving data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, addeventlistener

I have the following code to create at runtime one form with some input fields and buttons (in a Firebase loop that i have cutted away because with or without it i have the same issue) in my Javascript application using DOM.

So here my snippet:

```js
var form = document.createElement("FORM");
var fieldset = document.createElement("FIELDSET");
var inputId = document.createElement("INPUT");
inputId.value = "ID";
fieldset.appendChild(inputId);
var inputVillage = document.createElement("INPUT");
inputVillage.value = "Villaggio";
fieldset.appendChild(inputVillage);
var inputImage = document.createElement("INPUT");
inputImage.value = "Immagine";
fieldset.appendChild(inputImage);
var buttonMod = document.createElement("INPUT");
buttonMod.setAttribute("type", "button");
buttonMod.value = "Modifica";
  // HERE my problem
buttonMod.addEventListener("click",tryfunc("Mark"));
  // or (same result)
// buttonMod.onclick(tryfunc);
fieldset.appendChild(buttonMod);
form.appendChild(fieldset);
document.body.appendChild(form);
```

```js
function tryfunc(name) {
 [...]
 document.write("Hello " + name);
 // I also tried with this instruction found here on stackoverflow
 // (but this generate other problems)
 //name.stopPropagation();
}
```

my tryfunc("xxx") is autofired at start of my application, how can prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function immediately: `tryfunc("Mark")`. Note, function invocation `()` parentesis. Instead, you need to have anonymous function and call yours from inside:

```
buttonMod.addEventListener("click", function() {
    tryfunc("Mark");
});
```

Comment: I am new wit DOM sorry if my question is not so deep, Thank you mate!